# HDD Caddies DL380 DL580

Tags: hard-drive, hp-proliant

I have a DL580 G5 with 2.5" HDD Drives

I am wondering if the caddies from DL380 G5 be used in DL580 G5. both do take 2.5" inch drives.

I do not have DL380 so cannot verify myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

From QuickSpecs: "Compatible with the following ProLiant servers that use 2.5" SFF drives: HP Proliant BL20p G4 , BL25p G2, BL45p G2, BL460c, BL465c, BL480c, BL685c, DL360 G4p, DL360 G5, DL365, DL380 G4, DL380 G5, DL385 G2, DL580 G3, DL580 G4, DL585 G2, DL585 G5, ML330 G6, ML350 G5, ML370 G4, ML370 G5, ML370 G6, ML570 G3, ML570 G4."

Comment: wow thank you, i searched a lot and couldn't find this, can you please share the original link or the pdf where this information is present

Comment: Search internet for 378343-002, looks like they pulled it from amazon or other site selling it.